# A possible generalization of Solomonoff's theorem

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Assume that $P$ and $Q$ are probability distribution on the binary tree,

i.e. $P$ and $Q$ are functions $\{0,1\}^{*} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

for every $x$: $P(x)=P(x0)+P(x1)$ and $P( \text{empty word})= 1$.

**Theorem**(Solomonoff)

Assume that  for some $c>0$ it holds that  for every $x$  $Q(x) \ge c P(x)$ .
Then:
$$ \sum_{x \in \{0,1\}^*} P(x) (P(0 | x) - Q(0 | x))^2 = O(- \log c).$$
(the same is true for $(P(1 | x) - Q(1 | x))^2$ since it is equal to 
$(P(0 | x) - Q(0 | x))^2$).

Usually this theorem is formulated in terms of computable (semi-)measures.
For the reader's convenience I represent the

**sketch of the proof.**
Denote the restrictions of $P$ and $Q$ on $\{0,1\}^n$ as $P_n$ and $Q_n$.

The Kullback–Leibler divergence $D(P_n | Q_n)$ is defined as $\sum_{x \in \{0,1\}^n} P_n(x) \log \frac{P_n(x)}{Q_n(x)}$.

**Lemma 1** $D(P_1 | Q_1) \ge (P(0) - Q(0))^2$.

For $b \in \{0,1\}, x \in \{ 0,1 \}^n$ denote by $P_{n+1}( \cdot | x)$ the 
probabilty distribution on $\{0,1\}$ with probabilities $P_{n+1}(0|x)$ and $P_{n+1}(1|x)$.

**Lemma 2**
 $$D(P_{n+1} | Q_{n+1}) =D(P_n | Q_n) + \sum_{x \in \{0,1\}^n}D(P_n(\cdot |x), Q_n(\cdot |x)).$$

Hence, $D(P_n | Q_n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{x \in \{0,1\}^k} D(P_k(\cdot |x), Q_k(\cdot |x))$.

By using this equality and the first  lemma we obtain:
$$D(P_n | Q_n) \ge  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{x \in \{0,1\}^k} P(x) (P(0|x) - Q(0|x))^2.$$ 
Therefore, 
$$\sum_{x \in \{0,1\}^*} P(x) (P(0 | x) - Q(0 | x))^2 = \lim_{n \to \infty}D(P_n | Q_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}P_n(x) \log \frac{P_n(x)}{Q_n(x)} \le \log c.$$
**End of the proof.**

Now assume that the condition $Q(x) \ge c P(x)$ only at some subset $T\subseteq \{0,1\}^*$. Assume also that we also have $P(x) \ge c Q(x)$ for every $x \in T$.

**Question:**  Is it true that then 
$$ \sum_{x \in T} P(x) (P(0 | x) - Q(0 | x))^2 = O(- \ln c) ?  $$

Comment: Can you state Solomonoff's full result, including what it means to "predict well", and give a reference?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the notation right: is $P(0|x)=P(x0)/P(x)$?

Comment: @fedja, yes. If $P(x)=0$ then $P(0 | x):=0$.

Comment: @AryehKontorovich The Solomonoff's theorem is  usually formulated for computable measures and semi-measures. You can find it the book of Li and Vitanyi: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781489984456.  
But in fact the computability is not important: if $Q(x) \ge c P(x)$ for every $x$ then the corresponding sum is less than $O(\log c)$. This result means that $P(0|x)$ is close to $Q(0|x)$ for random (according to measure P) $x$. So $Q$ can predict $P$ well.